# Add namespace and attribute to a XML

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

I have a xml file and I need to add a namespace and an attribute associated to the namespace.

The original xml looks this way

```
<ns0:quakeml xmlns:ns0="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2" xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2">
<eventParameters publicID="smi:URI/id">
<event publicID="URI/id">
```

I need to add a namespace defined as

```
xmlns:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1"
```

and a parameter to the event tag

```
catalog:datasource="foo"
```

Actually I do :

```
xml.set("{http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1}catalog", 'http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1')
```

so I get

```
<ns0:quakeml xmlns:ns0="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2" xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:ns1="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1" ns1:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1">
```

not exactly the same I want.

To insert the attribute I do

```
event.attrib['eventsource'] = 'foo'
```

but it doesnt add any namespace